# How do football APIs get their data?

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I am wondering how sport APIs get their data.

Do they use web scraping or web crawling?

If they do: is it legal to create my web scraper to gather data?

I checked various sites and they all lead to different API/Feed, but how do these feeds get their data?

And how do they update it so fast (live scores)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they get it from the contribution of the community.
More Info: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/guide-to-football-and-soccer-data-and-apis

Answer (score 0):

Some, like Opta, have their own staff watching the games and updating data, but then they charge large amounts of money for access.

The smaller companies mainly scrape the data (technically in the public doman, so legal)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try https://xmlsoccer.com; they are a Danish company, and cover most international soccer leagues.